# Is there any effect to SEO if I redirecting the .com to the .app of my domain?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect

So, say I purchase a brand new `example.com` and `example.app`. I want to redirect all traffic reaching `example.com` to `example.app` (i.e. the `.com` is a pure redirect).

Does that have any impact on SEO?

**Note 1:** I'm asking as many (most/all) SEO *gurus* say that you're expected to have a `.com` and the other extensions do not get as high a ranking from Google. So I'm wondering whether I should make the `.com` the official site and redirect the `.app` to the `.com` (which in a way would be rather sad).

**Note 2:** Some background, I'm developing an Android app (and later I'll have an iPhone clone) and I think that using the `example.app` makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to redirect all traffic reaching `example.com` to `example.app` (i.e. the `.com` is a pure redirect).
>
> Does that have any impact on SEO?

It means that any links to the `.com` will pass some link juice to the `.app` domain, though less than if the `.app` domain were linked directly. I am fairly certain that there are no other SEO implications. So, fairly useless from an SEO standpoint, though there may be some value in being able to redirect boomers who automatically type ".com" after every website name. Also, it could be very much worth it to prevent squatters from buying up the name themselves and trying to compete with you.

> many (most/all) SEO gurus say that you're expected to have a .com and the other extensions do not get as high a ranking from Google.

"Expected to have a .com" is one thing, but these gurus are wrong that it affects ranking in any direct way. Dot com domains can be better for consumer recognizability especially with an older audience, but they do not inherently rank better according to my experience and according to Google themselves:

> They will require the same geotargeting settings and configuration, and they won’t have more weight or influence in the way we crawl, index, or rank URLs.
>
> [Google's handling of new top level domains](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/07/googles-handling-of-new-top-level.html)

Comment: Excellent, the linked page says it all. On my end I already have the `.com`, `.org`, and `.app` and for now I want to redirect the `.com` and `.org` to the `.app` so people can use `.com` and I'm a little bit protected from others trying to buy the same name with a different TLD.